# How to forward IP from different subnets on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, routing, hyper-v

I have two Hyper-V VMs and two private switches.

One VM (let's call it `RIPLEY-W1`) has two ethernet cards, one connected to `Private Switch 1` with address `192.168.0.11` the other to `Private Switch 2` with address `192.168.1.11`.

The other VM (`RIPLEY-W2`) has one ethernet card connected to `Private Switch 1` with address `192.168.0.12`.

If I `ping 192.168.1.11` from `RIPLEY-W2` I cannot get to the net. I've tried adding a specific route by using `route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.12` on `RIPLEY-W2` and enabling forwarding on `RIPLEY-W1` by setting `IPEnableRouter` to `1` (did not work) and using `Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled; Set-Service RemoteAccess -StartupType Automatic; Start-Service RemoteAccess` (did not work either).

Pinging `192.168.0.11` from `RIPLEY-W2` works fine.

I could make this work fine with two Ubuntu VMs with the same virtual setup, using `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` on the target machine and `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.12 dev eth0` on the origin machine.

Is it even possible to route between those two subnets on Windows?